# Dependencies in Rubber?

Tags: compiling, rubber, build-system

I have several figures compiled independently into several pdf files.
Rubber works great in their compilation.
The main document is compiling great with rubber as well.

How can I add dependency (if figure pdf is outdated then recompile) into Rubber?

Comment: Do you mean that you use rubber + pdflatex to compile figure1.tex -> figure1.pdf, and then you have main.tex which uses `\includegraphics{figure1.pdf}`?

Comment: And in that case, a quick'n'dirty solution would be to simply run `rubber -Wall figure*.tex && rubber -Wall main.tex`. It doesn't re-compile figures if they are already up-to-date. You can write a one-line shell script that does that for you. For a better solution, I'd like to read the manual, but someone has broken the rubber home page, and I can't find documentation any more...

Comment: That's exactly what I need.

Comment: Instead of a shell script Makefile would be better. But I thought that rubber intends to replace it!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to add something like this in your `rules.ini` file (I haven't tested this; read the manual and see the predefined examples in `rules.ini`):

```
[textopdf]
target = (.*)\.pdf
source = \1.tex
cost = 1
rule = shell
command = rubber -Wall $source
message = converting $source to PDF
```

This assumes that running `rubber -Wall figure1.tex` actually generates `figure1.pdf`.

Note that you don't need to manipulate the "global" `share/rubber/rules.ini` file; it should be possible to add a directive like `% rubber: rules myrules.ini` in your `main.tex`, and then put the above rule in `myrules.ini`. (Again, I haven't tested this.)

Answer (score 0):

Use just the rubber directive watch, by adding just the following line to your latex document:

```
% rubber: watch figure1.pdf
```

See rubber man page with

```
man rubber
```

to learn everything about rubber directives.

Comment: A late welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).